# Will a constant std::string make a copy of the data it is initialized with?

Tags: c++, string, copy, constants

Say I have a char array with a number of c-strings, like so:

```
char strings[] =
{
    "One c-string\0Another c-string\0Third c-string"
};
```

And an array that gives me the indices of each c-string:

```
int stringIndices[] =
{
    0, 13, 30
}
```

These are not constant, the strings array may be modified, and the string indices array updates appropriately. It should only happen rarely, but it might happen once or twice. Meaning, these two arrays are not constant.

If I wanted to make a constant std::string to pass one of these strings around, but not modify them, I can do:

```
std::string const k_2ndString { &strings[ stringIndices[1] ] };
```

My question is, will this involve making a copy of the second string for k_2ndString to hold on to, or would k_2ndString just point it's internal data pointer to the strings array?

I'd rather avoid making copies, and it seems like a complex scheme, so I was thinking I could instead just have an array of std::strings:

```
std::array<std::string,3> strings;
```

Initialize it, and avoid the second array and indirection by simply referring to strings[1] for example if I want the second string. Initializing this array would be a bit more of a pain, but not by much.

Comment: The array of `std::string` seems so much better.

Comment: yes, it will create a copy. It would have made a lousy class if it allowed someone to change its data unnoticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your requirement clearly. Then you want to have a string which stores the global data and other string should use reference of that string based on the index. It should not make another copy. If that is the requirement then it can be done with this code:

```
const string strings[] = {"One string", "Another string", "Third string"};   

int stringIndices[] =
{
    0, 1, 2
};

string const& k_2ndString = strings[ stringIndices[1] ];
```

Please let me know if I have misunderstood your requirement or this code does not fulfill the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple.

`const std::string strings[] = {"One string", "Another string", "Third string"};`

Or

`const char *const strings[] = {"One string", "Another string", "Third string"};`

To answer your question, `std::string` always copies the input string and stores it internally. If you make these strings global or static, it should only happen once and so it's not a big deal.

Comment: String literals are not writable, so it would be a permitted optimization for a `const` string initialized from a string literal to internally point to the literal. (I don't know if any compiler does this or not)

Comment: The contents of the strings could change, but this solution makes them constant. I don't want to store constant strings, I just want to be able to pass around constant references to the strings.

Comment: `const std::string& strings[] = {str1, str2, str3};`